# How to update data in database through URL in PHP

Tags: php

I am new in web development. I want to update data of my database from URL like this:
Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this my code? Because I am trying from last 2 days but not able to find out the solution. Hoping to answer from the community.
Thanks in advance!!

"http://localhost/repos/index.php?id=1&status=approved"

> index.php

```
<?php

    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","angdb");

    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $data=array();
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'GET':
            response(getData());
            break;

        case 'PUT':
            response(updateData());

        default:
            #code...
            break;
    }

    function getData()
    {
        global $conn;

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="AND id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }


        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from vendor where status='pending' ".$where);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"changeColumn"=>$row['changeColumn'],"type"=>$row['type'],"timestamp"=>$row['timestamp'],"status"=>$row['status'],"name"=>$row['name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function updateData()
    {
        global $conn;
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$_PUT);

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="where id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update vendor set status='".$_PUT['status']."'".$where);


        if($query==true)
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Not updated");
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function response($data)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: How are you sending the URL? Browsers don't send `PUT` requests. They send `GET` when you put the URL in the location bar, and `GET` or `POST when you submit a form, depending on the `method` attribute.

Comment: @Oops no. Undefined index: status in C:\nginx\www\repos\Sportaz-repo\VaamozWeb\VaamozBusiness\RestApi\VaamozStore\AdminStore\angular_admin\php\index.php on line 68

68 line means $query part

Comment: @Barmar i am trying through postman

Answer (score 0):

The status is in the query parameter, not the posted data. So `$_PUT['status']` should be `$_GET['status']`